# Avoid the Git repo top folder when pushing to server?

Tags: github, terminal

I want to push my `github.com/username/reponame` to my live webserver `domain.com/demo/`. I've managed to correctly push the code to that location, but it's including the top-level directory of my repo, putting the files into `domain.com/demo/reponame/`.

I'm very new to Git and SSH, and I'm not understanding how I should push/pull so that the top level folder of my GitHub repo isn't included.

**Answer**: had to change `git clone git@github.com:username/reponame.git` to `git clone git@github.com:username/reponame.git .` - that period at the end ignores the top level folder.

Comment: `git` will pull what you had `git commit`ed. So, you can `git commit` only a particular path or file, and then `git push`. So don't use `git commit -a`

Comment: I did the following: 

Went into the folder on the server through SSH, then: 

git clone git@github.com:username/reponame.git

Answer (score 0):

To add to your answer, I would rather clone as a bare repo:

```
git clone --bare git@github.com:username/reponame.git /a/path/different/from/reponame
```

(no final dot here), in order to be able to:

- push to that repo, using an ssh url `ssh://yourServeerAccount@yourServer://a/path/different/from/reponame.git` (you only push to a bare repo)
  See an example in "[git push/clone to new server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1402783/6309)".
- setup a hook which would `cd` to `/demo/reponame` and `checkout HEAD` in it: see this "[`post-receive` hook example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11724354/6309)".