# How to clone a local git repository to a repository on the server?

Tags: git, github, ssh

I am currently using this command ::

**git clone --bare path/in/local ssh://path/in/server**

But this command is creating a new git folder named **ssh://path/in/server** in my local system and then cloning the local git repository in it.

So,I need to know if there is a way to have it done using the **git clone** command specifically.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I clone a local, normal repository as bare repository directly onto remote host?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16431855/can-i-clone-a-local-normal-repository-as-bare-repository-directly-onto-remote-h)

Answer (score 2):

`git clone` can only create local repositories.

If you want to create a repository elsewhere, you'll need to create an empty repository on the remote machine (for that you typically need shell access or some kind of admin interface), then add it as a remote in your local repo and push to it.