# Git - how to push a new git-project on a server?

Tags: git

I'm actually trying to push my work on my personal git server.

I just made a `git init test`, added and commited a test file, and added a remote pointing to server with `git remote add`.
I didn't create a git repository on my server, so my `ssh://git@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX/opt/git/test.git` remote does not already exist.

I have the `does not appear to be a git repository` error.

The user "git" is the owner of the /opt/git directory.

Isn't that possible to create the non-existing repository by pushing to it for the first time? 
I could do it with ssh but this isn't very pratical... Isn't there an other way? I found no option for that.

I thank you for your help and I apologize for my possible spelling mistakes (I'm french).

Comment: check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402390/git-push-clone-to-new-server

Comment: "I could do it with ssh but this isn't very pratical..." Why isn't ssh practical for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no way for a push to happen automatically, if the remote specified is not a git repo itself.

You will have to `ssh` into your server, and run a `git init` to create an empty git repository.

It seems to me that you are trying to host your repository on your server, if that is the case, I would suggest using a [bare repository](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5540883/1860929). Basically, when initializing the repo, use `git init --bare`.

Also, I would suggest that you go through [the various protocols](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols) for setting up git server, you are using the `git` protocol which requires additional steps as mentioned in the link, and that should save you some effort debugging the setup.

Comment: So I really have to access to my server with ssh.
Thank you, I only wanted to know that, that answers my question.

Comment: You can also access the server using `git` protocol. On the remote side - create your repository `git init --bare test` and then run `git daemon` - this will start a listener on port 9418. Then you can run `git remote add foo git://server/`

Answer (score 1):

From what the error says, it seems that you should do a `git init` in the remote server directory before you push to it.

Comment: So I must really access to my server in ssh to do that? This is the only way?

Comment: I guess so because git needs to identify it as an actual repository for it to do its work. That's what I think.